# Does gnosis-safe support meta-transactions?

Tags: gnosis-safe, meta-transactions

Does gnosis-safe have support for meta-transactions? Specifically I would like to integrate Biconomy's gasless transactions for my dapp users when interacting with a gnosis safe contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible via the UI, but there's a gas refund mechanism on the contract level. Basically you can create a transaction and tell the safe to refund gas for executing.
But still the gas has to be paid by someone.
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a wallet for each user and Biconomy can relay meta transactions on behalf of the user. You get to whitelist which Dapp contracts and for which user SCWs you're sponsoring gas for.

Comment: So if i understand what you're saying, a gnosis safe is used per user and the gas is taken from the gnosis safe? In that case what is the biconomy gas tank for? What i ultimately want to do is use the gas tank to pay for transactions to and from the multisig gnosis safe by multiple users (to a single safe).